# Database Boolean and DateTime naming convention

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, naming-conventions

I am creating a Posts SQL table where I need to save:
1. If the post is approved;
2. When the post was approved.

I am considering naming these columns IsApproved and ApprovedAt:

```
create table dbo.Posts
(
  Id int identity not null,
  IsApproved bit null,
  ApprovedAt datetime null
)
```

Is there any convention for such a case?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support `boolean`, but your naming convention is reasonable.

Comment: That was a typo. I corrected to bit. I could also just have only one column named "Approved datetime" which when Null would mean that is not approved. Not sure if it would be worse for queries and confusing in some other cases. What do you think?

Comment: Having two columns does allow you to get into contradictory scenarios, an Approved date with no IsApproved set or visa versa. I would implement the IsApproved as a computed column, or logic within your DAO

Comment: Never use a nullable `BIT` column unless there's a really good reason to, because you raise the specter of what it means for a binary condition to be "unknown". Prefer `NOT NULL` and a sensible default (in this case, `0`). Or, as you mentioned, if it can never be the case that `IsApproved = 1` and `ApprovedAt IS NULL`, then make `IsApproved` a computed column (`IsApproved = CONVERT(BIT, CASE WHEN ApprovedAt IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)`).

Comment: You can still call it ApprovedDateTime even when you have a separate bit, but we've quite often used the nullability of the field as an indicator. Keep in mind that it may affect the use of indexes and therefore the performance of your queries.

Comment: I would argue against having two separate columns in this case - for the same reason Jeroen Mostert wrote in his comment - A post that is approved must have an approval date, and a post that has an approval date is obviously approved - so there really is no point of keeping the `IsApproved` column.

As for the naming conventions, Is... and ...Date are very reasonable for bit and date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any convention for such a case? No.

But I like your choice (is also my convention for booleans and dates) because:

- `IsApproved` is a *boolean* and starts with **Is**
- `ApprovedAt` is a *date* and ends with **At**

I share some "conventions":

https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/better-sql-schema

https://github.com/ghowland/Dasonic